# Second order interpolation scheme

Tags: finite-difference, numerical-analysis, computational-physics, discretization, interpolation

On a grid I am having the values of a physical quantity say for example Temperature, at the E,W,N,S and P node all of them being calculated using a second order discretization scheme. I want a second order accurate estimate of the value of Temperature at point X. How to get that.

Note- I can get a second order accurate value of temperature at point IP1 (using second order polynomial fitting with point E, W and P) and at point IP2 (using second order polynomial fitting with point N, S and P). Both IP1 and IP2 are at distance Δx/4Δx/4 from point P.

Kindly refer to the stencil for details.

[image: Stencil]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2D you would need a bi-quadratic interpolation function such as $(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2)(b_0 + b_1 y + b_2 y^2)$ giving rise to 9 undetermined coefficients. Thus you need 9 points where the values are known then you can determine these coefficients.

At the least you need incomplete polynomial up to 2nd order for a 2nd order estimate, i.e., $\{1,x,y,x^2,y^2,xy\}$ with 6 coefficients, thus you need 6 points.

With 5 points and 6 coefficients you will have an under determined linear least squares problem. You can convert it to an over determined system by adding more points, especially if you are on, say, a finite difference grid. You can find details in any numerical analysis text book. [See also this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)). I give some basics below.

Your goal is to find the polynomial function coefficients - the function itself is linear in the coefficients. Now express the sum of the square of error between interpolated values $v^I$ and actual values $v^A$ at $n>6$ points as:
\begin{align*}
E = \sum_{i=1}^n(v^I(a_p, \mathbf x_i) - v^A_i)^2 \qquad& v^I \text{ is linear in } a_p \text{ evaluated at } \mathbf x_i \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n(v^I_p(\mathbf x_i) a_p - v^A_i)^2\qquad& \text{p}^{th} (1...6) \text{ coefficient of } v^I \text{ at } \mathbf x_i \\
{{\partial E}\over{\partial a_k}} = \sum_{i=1}^n 2(v^I_p(\mathbf x_i) a_p - v^A_i) v^I_p(\mathbf x_i)\delta_{pk} = 0\qquad& \text{minimize w.r.t. } a_k \\
\implies \sum_{i=1}^n v^I_k(\mathbf x_i) v^I_p(\mathbf x_i) a_p = \sum_{i=1}^n v^I_k(\mathbf x_i) v^A_i\qquad&
\end{align*}

Clearly if you have an over determined system, you can also go with the approach of bi-quadratic functions with 9 coefficients (on a 3x3 grid) at each point.

Comment: does that mean if i have the values of corner nodes (to P) which are not marked in the figure above then i can get the value at X (2nd order accurate). I am trying to avoid this situation since the stencil grows in size and i intend to solve implicitly for the values at each node. How to proceed with lest squares thing. (sorry for asking this trivial question)

Comment: Don't understand your 1st point on corner nodes and stencil growth. Please add a picture to help your explanation. I have added some details on linear least squares problem to the answer.

Comment: By corner points i mean to say that making the cells NE (north east), SE, NW and SW as part of the stencil.

Comment: Got it. I want to say that is the cost of doing business. In fact looking at your original points IP1 and IP2, they may be 2nd order accurate in E-W and N-S direction but not necessarily with respect to N-S and E-W directions respectively. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? what is the big picture here?

Comment: well the bigger picture is that the stencil shown here arises at one of the faces (in 3D geometry) in adaptive mesh refinement using octtree. The idea is to form a second order accurate laplacian operator at heterogeneous faces  where coarse-fine boundaries occur. [The Paper (go to page 6 and 7 (577 and 578)] (http://pages.csam.montclair.edu/~yecko/icodes/Popinet_GERRIS.pdf). The stencil shown above occurs in 3D rendition of the method.

Comment: Looked at the reference quickly. Clearly all these points are aligned in the same direction as your Laplacian (either E-W or N-S). See Eq 9, where $\nabla_d \phi$ is computed from $\phi, \phi_7,$ and  $\phi_6$ and how $\phi_6$ itself needs to be interpolated appropriately. The whole scheme is predicated on the underlying data structure being able to support efficient computation, but *it is possible*.

Comment: the paper only describes the 2D stencil for quadtrees whereas the stencil I have drawn occurs in a 3D case(octree) when case b of Figure 3 (see the paper) occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Don't know if you have a question.